# Spritekit Scene content is zoomed in

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene, skview

I am presenting a Game Controller/Game Scene programmatically from a View Controller (which passes a `difficulty` string to it) like so :

```
class GameController: UIViewController {

    var difficulty: String!

    override func loadView() {

        self.view = SKView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.difficulty = difficulty
        // Present the scene
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    }
}
```

However when the scene appears on the screen, all the content is "zoomed in" (`SKSpriteNode`s, `SKLabel`s, etc.)

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance.

PS: presenting via the SKS works OK, there is just a problem of `SKLabel` positioning on iPad. The problem with this method is that I haven't been able to find how to pass my custom variable `difficulty` to the scene via the SKS even though I changed its custom class to mine in the Storyboard so that should do too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have 2 questions here. First is what's wrong with my current setup and secondly can I use the sks file and still pass data along.

to answer the second question, yes

```
if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

    self.gameScene = gameScene
    self.gameScene.stage = 1
    self.gameScene.setupBasedOnStage()
    self.gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    self.view?.presentScene(self.gameScene, transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1.0))
}
```

You are able to set any custom property before revealing the page (in this case it's stage), and if you needed to you can call a setup function to load info/graphics based on the stage.

I use sks files for my scenes and setup them up like this all the time.

Comment: Hey @Ron thank you for your reply but when presenting with the SKS I am unable to access the `var difficulty: String!` in my SKScene class (which is set as custom class in my SKS file). Is there anything special to set up ?

Comment: where is the variable setup? inside the class but outside a function? is it set to private?   maybe post a little but of the scene class file to your question.   also if you setup your string as    var difficulty = ""    you avoid having to treat it as an optional

Comment: `.aspectFill` does it for me